# Tortoise SVN like Overlays on files in Perforce

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, perforce

I have used Tortoise SVN before and really loved the overlays on files and folders (like shown in the screenshot below).

[image]

**QUESTION:** Is it possible to have such overlays for Perforce Helix P4V?

Answer (score 1):

Perforce Helix has a [tool that provides some level of integration with Windows File Explorer](https://www.perforce.com/plugins-integrations/file-explorer-plugin). However, it seems that it does not support status icons.

Comment: Old versions of P4EXP used to support file icons (sync and checkout status); if you can find an old build they should still work with newer servers.

Answer (score 0):

It's alos supported icon with current latest release (2020.1/2034812) on Win10
If the icon is not shown, you may check this [article](https://community.perforce.com/s/article/2771)

[image]